# Running an external executable in Python interactively

Tags: python, c, subprocess

A simple C program is compiled using `gcc test.c -o test.exe`:

```
        /* TEST.C */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define TRUE 1

int main (void)
{
  char p[256];
  strcpy(p, "start\0");
  printf("Welcome!\n");
  while (TRUE)
  {
    printf("Input: ");
    if (fgets(p, 255, stdin) == NULL)  break;
    if (p[0] == 'q')                   break;
    printf("You Entered: %s\n", p);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The subprocess module in Python portends to start a program and grab its `stdin` and `stdout`. Simple test using the above program:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT

output = open("test.out","w")
ris = subprocess.Popen(executable="test.exe", args="", stdin=PIPE,
                       stdout=output, stderr=STDOUT,
                       universal_newlines=True, shell=True)  
com = ris.communicate(input='bye\n')
com = ris.communicate(input='q\n')
output.close()
```

appears to loop infinitely on the first communicate command, filling `test.out` with:

```
Welcome!
You Entered: bye
You Entered: bye
You Entered: bye
You Entered: bye
.
.
.
```

until the user interrupts the python process. Using `ris.stdin.write('bye\n')` instead of `communicate` does not seem to send input at all even when followed by `ris.stdin.flush()`.

What is the proper way to interactively run an executable with `subprocess`?  The intention is to leave a single instance of the program running in the background while multiple inputs are passed in through `stdin` and the corresponding outputs are read from `stdout` or `stderr`

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* by using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration `p[0]`, which is indeterminate.

Comment: Before asking how to run a program in Python, you should make sure the program runs correctly from the console.

Comment: You failed to check the return value of `scanf()`. I believe that it is returning `EOF`.

Comment: Aside: One should avoid `void main(void)`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/204483/8747

Comment: @Robᵩ: As `p[0] is encountered first, there is no use in meditating if `scanf` updates `p`. Once you encounter undefined behaviour, all bets are off.

Comment: Runs fine from the command line and using `subprocess.run("test.exe")` and entering a sequence like hi, bye, q. @Rob, you think characters are being sent other than what are listed as the input in the call to `communicate`?

Comment: No, I think the stream is being closed after the first four characters are sent. The subsequent `scanf()` calls return EOF and the process never exits.

Comment: @Olaf - you are correct in your "all bets are off" assertion. I still claim it is worth contemplating what happens *after* he fixes that problem.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Yes, that is the next issue to be addressed.

Comment: @Robᵩ My question is answered by using `ris.stdin.write`, but I am still curious about why checking for `EOF` doesn't seem to prevent the loop when `com = ris.communicate('bye\n')' is called.

Comment: You're not checking correctly. Re-read the doc for [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). In neither your original program nor your edited program do you check the return value of either of those calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the errors in your C program that have been mentioned, you are calling `.communicate()` more than once. `.communicate()` is single-use function that sends *all* of its data to the subprocess and waits for the subprocess to exit.

If you must use `.communicate()`, use it this way:

```
com = ris.communicate(input='bye\nq\n')
```

Alternatively, you can use `ris.stdin.write()`, like so:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT

output = open("test.out","w")
ris = subprocess.Popen(executable="/tmp/test.exe", args="", stdin=PIPE,
                       stdout=output, stderr=STDOUT,
                       universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
com = ris.stdin.write('bye\n')
com = ris.stdin.write('q\n')
ris.stdin.flush()
output.close()
ris.wait()
```

Comment: I would rather not use communicate. `ris.stdin.write()` or somoething like this that can send a stream of input would be much preferable.